# Filter not filtering

Tags: views

I have a field for which I used REWRITE RESULTS for a dropbox to turn 1 -> yes, and turn 0 -> no.

I want to add a filter to allow users to sort this field. When I create my sort, I get 1 // 0 as sorting options (rather than yes, no).

How do I get yes/no (which I had previously established in rewrite results) be what shows up for my sort of that field?

Thank you!

Tan

Answer (score 0):

Is this a boolean field? If so, you should be able to use the Output format dropbox that appears when you click on the field. Yes/No is one of the choices. (I'm using Views in Drupal 8--I don't know whether it's the same for Drupal 7.)

Comment: Hi Lisa,Yes!! This is a boolean field. I choose dropdown as the option for output of the filter, but then all of my results disappear (empty table). Would you have a suggestion for this? 

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if we're talking about the same dropdown. Under the FIELDS heading, click on the boolean field. Then you should see an "Output format" dropdown that includes Yes/No in addition to 1 / 0, True / False, etc.